Joomla! 5 Unknown column 'id = 1' in 'where clause' error
I am trying to connect to the #__contact_details db and get some info from there for a custom module.
public function getContact(Registry $params, SiteApplication $app)
{
    
    $db = Factory::getContainer()->get('DatabaseDriver');
    
    $cid   = (int) $params->get('main_contact');

    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    $query
        ->select($db->quoteName(['name', 'con_position', 'address', 'suburb']))
        ->from($db->quoteName('#__contact_details'))
        ->where($db->quoteName(('id') . ' = '. $cid));


    $db->setQuery($query);
       
    
    return $list = $db->loadObject();
}

it gives Unknown column 'id = 1' in 'where clause' error. There is a column id in the db. How do i correct this? Thank you so much.

I had a problem with excessive parentheses.  I shouldn't have passed my entire conditional expression into quoteName().
$db->quoteName(('id') . ' = '. $cid)
#             ||----| irrelevant
#             |--------------------| bad

Only the column name should be quoted as an identifier:
$db->quoteName('id') . ' = '. $cid

Working script:
public function getContact(Registry $params, SiteApplication $app)
{
    $db = Factory::getContainer()->get('DatabaseDriver');
    $cid = $params->get('main_contact');
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query
        ->select($db->quoteName(['name', 'con_position', 'address', 'suburb']))
        ->from($db->quoteName('#__contact_details'))
        ->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' = '. (int)$cid);
    $db->setQuery($query);
    return $db->loadObject();
}


Please accept your answer to show that issue has been resolved. Thank you for taking the time to come back and share your solution.
